# HTML Form - Create list which displays options as you type in Wix iFrame

Tags: html, forms, iframe, html-lists, velo

I have an HTML form in an iFrame on my Wix website. In a particular field, students will enter their current school or university. It would be great if students could type their university, and suggestions may appear for them. Currently, in our CRM there are many variations of the same school that students have typed so this would clean things up a little.

Secondly, if it is possible, how could I make it so that if they type the school abbreviation, it will also list the school?

Eg. Typing 'American' or 'AUC' would display 'American University in Cairo'

Thanks!
James

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Wix and I'm not sure if it has its place on StackOverflow but is it autocomplete that you are looking for ?
If it is, [this might help you](https://wix.com/app-market/site-search-2/overview)